# YUI AutoComplete Returning Entire JSON Object

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement [YUI's AutoComplete](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/autocomplete/#locating-results) widget, however I can't get it to display what I want properly.

Here's the call which pulls the JSON Object

```
var dataSource = new Y.DataSource.IO({
    source: '/search'
});
Y.one('#search-string').plug(Y.Plugin.AutoComplete, {
    resultHighlighter: 'phraseMatch',
    resultTextLocator: 'response',
    requestTemplate: '?search-string={query}',
    source: ACDataSource,
    maxResults: 5
}
```

But the entire object is displayed in my autocomplete box

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "name": "Billy Bob",
      "id": 155,
      "address": "123 Little Billy Ln",

    }
}
```

I am only trying to display "name" values, not the whole object. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your `resultListLocator` and also set your `resultTextLocator` correctly. From the documentation

> While AutoComplete automatically knows how to handle results that come
>   back as a simple array, it needs some extra information in order to
>   find a result array that's buried inside an object hierarchy. That's
>   where the resultListLocator config attribute comes in.

and

> The resultTextLocator config attribute can be used to tell
>   AutoComplete how to find some text within an individual result object,
>   much like the resultListLocator attribute tells AutoComplete how to
>   find an array of results within a response object.

By the way, you seem to have mistyped your JSON - the array is not closed. Assuming content is your **results array**

```
resultListLocator: 'content',
resultTextLocator: 'name',
```

should get it working

Comment: Thanks @potatopeelings, unfortunately the above settings don't return anything. The only settings which have returned results is `resultTextLocator: 'response'` (which returns that entire JSON string).

Comment: I tried removing my defined Y.io.Datasource and setting my URL on the AutoComplete's `source` attribute, then the Locators started working. Thanks much